# Is there a level cap in 1-Bit Rogue?

Tags: 1-bit-rogue

I got to dungeon level 50 and amassed some 2000 gold. On the character select screen, I can level up starting at like 60 gold and +5 gold per level after.

The swordsman gets +1 HP per level up, but there appears to be a max of 99 HP. You can easily collect +1 max HP per level (over 50 dungeon levels, that'll add up). So, I'm thinking it only makes sense to level up so far.

So, finally, is there a level cap?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no level cap. ([Source](http://yurugame.info/post/one-bit-rogue-walkthrough-01.html))

> レベル上げなし means "no level cap"

Also, no matter what level you are, if you get beaten you'll be reset to level 1 floor 1. ([Source](http://yurugame.info/post/one-bit-rogue-review-01.html))

> 敵に負ければレベル１に戻ってフロア１やからり直し means, "if you lose you'll be returned to floor 1 to redo" (direct translation)

Comment: Thank you! Could you provide a short translation of the relevant part of each article? For example, I read the Google translation for the 1st article and didn't see where it mentions no level cap.

Comment: @AnthonyMastrean done! Sorry, thought Google Translate would be sufficient >.<

Comment: Thank you! I might be out of practice reading Google translations :)

Comment: I have another question that you might be able to find/translate/answer (given your language skills, you might watch this tag for future questions). https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/294252/how-many-artifacts-are-there-do-they-have-any-effect