# How many artifacts are there, do they have any effect?

Tags: ios, 1-bit-rogue

I noticed that I'm collecting artifacts by defeating the dragons on every 10th level. I get that this is some kind of goal for the game (collect 5 artifacts in a single playthrough). The collected artifacts seem to persist in my character select screen and across playthroughs for that class.

As the swordsman, I have a starting artifact (some kind of banner, what does this do?) and four empty slots. There's also a `Reset` button. I'm assuming that's to reset my collected artifacts.

That leads me to think that there's more than 5 unique artifacts and that there might be some reason to collect different sets of artifacts? Is that so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Post-game edit**: Just finished the game and I can conclude that the starting/subsequent artifacts have no effect on your game whatsover. 
Also, it is possible to finish the game with a level one character (I just did).

<s>I have no idea what the starting banner's effect on the gameplay is</s>, but it's on every character you start with. It's called the 'Ashes of Life', and story-wise, in King Boldof's request, he mentions

> Collect the four artifacts that slumber in our kingdom.
>   When those artifacts and our heirloom, the Ashes of Life, comes together...
>   Peace will rule on Earth.

The other four slots are for your artifacts. You can get more artifacts by [defeating the dragon every 10 floors](http://yurugame.info/post/one-bit-rogue-review-01.html).

> 1ビットローグは、10フロア毎に強敵「ドラゴン」が登場します。ドラゴンを倒す事ができると、やり込み要素「アーティファクト」を入手する事ができます。

When you defeat a dragon, you get a random +1 to your attack or durability.

> 10, 20, 30, 40, 50回で出現するドラゴンを倒すと、攻撃力(ATK)または武器耐久度(DCY)が上昇します

The reset button is translated from "Give up" in Japanese, so if you press that (and the confirmation button), you'll be returned to the main menu with your gold / levels intact. It's probably better to give up than to die to an enemy, I guess.

Source: Me. Downloaded the game and trying it out in Japanese now.